# Discrete colours in Geopandas map

Tags: python, geopandas, colormap

I am making a map in Geopandas, whereby I want to discretely color the different vegetation protection classes - "VMA_CAT". The vegetation protection classes are:

B - E-dom, B - O-dom, B - LeastC, B - O-subdom, C - E-dom, C - O-dom, C - LeastC, C - O-subdom, and Clear - VMA.

In this instance, the choropleth color ramps are not suitable for coloring the various vegetation protection classes.

Is there any way to discretely color each vegetation protection class?

Below are the table structure, data types, and code to generate the map.

Table

```
        VMA_dff = VMA_dff[["Property_ID", "SMA", "Property_Area(ha)","VMA_CAT", 
        "VMA_Area(ha)","VMA_%","geometry"]]
```

Data types

```
Property_ID             int32
SMA                     int32
Property_Area(ha)     float64
VMA_CAT                object
VMA_Area(ha)          float64
VMA_%                 float64
geometry             geometry
dtype: object
```

```
m = VMA_dff.explore(column='VMA_CAT',
               tooltip=["Property_ID","Property_Area(ha)","VMA_CAT","VMA_Area(ha)","VMA_%" ],
               popup = False,
               cmap='tab20_r', #matplotlibhttps://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html
               legend=True,
               tiles='OpenStreetMap',
               color = 'white',
               style_kwds =dict(color="gray", weight=0.5),
                            
              )
folium.TileLayer('CartoDB positron', control=True).add_to(m) 
folium.TileLayer('Stamen Toner', control=True).add_to(m) 

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

Comment: What is the question and where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list where the vegetation protection classes are the keys and the required discrete color are matplotlib color classes https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html.

```
color_discrete_map={
                    "B - E-dom": "purple",
                    "B - O-dom": "darkorange",
                    "B - O-subdom": "orange",
                    "B - LeastC": "green",
                    "C - E-dom": "fuchsia",
                    "C - O-dom": "moccasin",
                    "C - O-subdom": "papayawhip",
                    "C - LeastC": "springgreen",
                    "Clear - VMA": "white",}
```

For Loop through the list and assign the values to the cmap variables.

```
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap([color_discrete_map[b] for b in VMA_dff.VMA_CAT.unique()])
```

Include the cmap variables into the map eg cmap=cmap

```
m = VMA_dff.explore(column='VMA_CAT',
               tooltip=["Property_ID","Property_Area(ha)","VMA_CAT","VMA_Area(ha)","VMA_%" ],
               popup = False,
               cmap=cmap, 
               legend=True,
               tiles='OpenStreetMap',    
               style_kwds =dict(color="gray", weight=0.75),
                            
              )
folium.TileLayer('CartoDB positron', control=True).add_to(m) 
folium.TileLayer('Stamen Toner', control=True).add_to(m) 
# use folium to add alternative tiles
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)  # use folium to add layer control
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).